# tess4j jna UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, maven, jna, tess4j

I m using Tess4J under maven, I already used the pom dependency everything is well downloaded in the .m2 repository, I also downloaded the tess4j jna wrapper from source forge. But what ever I do I m still getting this exception :

```
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Found library resource at jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Looking for library 'libtesseract305'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: C:\Tess4J\lib\win32-x86-64;C:\Tess4J\lib;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64
Trying C:\Tess4J\lib\win32-x86-64\libtesseract305.dll
Adding system paths: []
Trying C:\Tess4J\lib\win32-x86-64\libtesseract305.dll
Looking for lib- prefix
Trying liblibtesseract305.dll
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for libtesseract305
Found library resource at jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/3.3.1/tess4j-3.3.1.jar!/win32-x86-64/libtesseract305.dll

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:75)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
at com.mycompany.mavenproject1.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:20)
```

I tried to add -Djna.library.path to my libtessract305.dll but no success

what should I do ?

Comment: "Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native." judging by javadocs you don't have many other options. Try running the jvm in verbose mode to see if it tells you where is looking for the native libraries. Your last sentence does not make much sense

Comment: Add the Java command-line option `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where JNA looks for the libraries. Make sure `-Djna.library.path` points to the *directory*, not the file.

Comment: @cubrr I added the log to my two computers because in my win10 asus is working fine and the load is well done, but in my second pc win7 is not, I updated my question. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of Tess4j, you are currently using .

Let's say,
version **3.2.1** worked well with **2010 VC++**, but for 
version **3.4.1**, you need to upgrade to VC++ 2013.

**Its is all about the compatibility of the DLLs with the VC++ version.**
Use Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable for Tess4J 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution is working for me, tesseract or tess4j is dependable to vs2015 not vs2013 as I did found in some threads. all I did was installing  Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Packages. and it works fine

Thanks for help